# terraform plan says I'm using a different version

Tags: terraform

`terraform plan` claims that I am using a different version than the one indicated in `terraform version`

When I run `terraform version` it says I have 1.5.2

```
Terraform v1.5.2
on windows_amd64
```

But when I run `terraform apply` it says I have 1.1.6

```
│ Error: Unsupported Terraform Core version
│
│   on versions.tf line 9, in terraform:
│    9:   required_version = ">= 1.2"
│
│ This configuration does not support Terraform version 1.1.6. To proceed,
│ either choose another supported Terraform version or update this version
│ constraint. Version constraints are normally set for good reason, so
│ updating the constraint may lead to other errors or unexpected behavior.
```

Comment: Are you using tfenv by any chance?

Comment: I am not using tfenv or any of those other tools related to switching terraform versions.

Answer (score 1):

I think we may have been discussing this same situation in [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/33439) earlier today! I'm going to summarize what we learned there in case someone else finds this question here in future after having a similar problem.

After seeing the fuller output of the `terraform plan` command we saw that it included the following:

```
Running plan in the remote backend. Output will stream here. Pressing Ctrl-C
will stop streaming the logs, but will not stop the plan running remotely.

Preparing the remote plan...

Waiting for the plan to start...

Terraform v1.1.6
on linux_amd64
```

This means that the local Terraform CLI asked Terraform Cloud to create a plan remotely rather than creating the plan on the local computer. It did that by running the version of Terraform configured in the remote workspace settings, which appears to be v1.1.6.

When using Terraform Cloud remote operations it's the Terraform version in the workspace settings that decides what is used for planning and applying, regardless of what version of Terraform you are using locally.

Comment: Indeed we also discussed on GitHub as well. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it could need to be re-initialised

try using terraform init first then see if that changes anything.